# openstack instance fails to spawn

Tags: openstack, openstack-swift, openstack-nova, devstack, openstack-cinder

i was able to spin up instance with cirros but i have created image of ubuntu 14.04 but i was unable to spin up instance using this image 
Please find the lob ebelow

Error: Failed to perform requested operation on instance "test", the instance has an error status: Please try again later [Error: Build of instance e47ff0b0-d427-46e0-b088-e535dcb755a4 aborted: Block Device Mapping is Invalid.].

Build of instance e47ff0b0-d427-46e0-b088-e535dcb755a4 aborted: Block Device Mapping is Invalid.
Code
500
Details
File "/opt/stack/nova/nova/compute/manager.py", line 1778, in _do_build_and_run_instance filter_properties) File "/opt/stack/nova/nova/compute/manager.py", line 1938, in _build_and_run_instance 'create.error', fault=e) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_utils/excutils.py", line 220, in **exit** self.force_reraise() File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_utils/excutils.py", line 196, in force_reraise six.reraise(self.type_, self.value, self.tb) File "/opt/stack/nova/nova/compute/manager.py", line 1903, in _build_and_run_instance block_device_mapping) as resources: File "/usr/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 17, in **enter** return self.gen.next() File "/opt/stack/nova/nova/compute/manager.py", line 2064, in _build_resources reason=e.format_message())
Created

Answer (score 1):

This is most probably due to a configuration error in Cinder.

I cannot say anything else about this without seeing your **cinder/volume.logs** but I suggest you to check out this question and answer in [ask.openstack.org](https://ask.openstack.org/en/question/91205/build-of-instance-aborted-block-device-mapping-is-invalid/).

Comment: This is what solved the issue. The Ubuntu-14.04 qcow2 image size was ~250MB. So I was giving volume size as 1GB. But it really needed more than 3GB which I could deduce from `/var/log/cinder/volume.logs`

Answer (score 0):

in Ocata double check endpoints. When you have no v2 cinder endpoint it could happen. Also always check if lvm is fully functional.

```
openstack endpoint list
```